# custom debian repository lists package but donot show or install

Tags: debian, apt, repository

I have created a .deb package (named astmbi) and created custom repository. 
`apt update` followed by `apt search astmbi` show the package 
`apt list astmbi` also show name of package 
However, `apt show astmbi` do not show package and `apt install astmbi` fails 
outputs are shown below

```
root@debian:/home/biochemistry# apt search astmbi
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
astmbi/unknown 1.0 arm64
  Bidirectional ASTM communication with medical equipments
```

```
root@debian:/home/biochemistry# apt list astmbi
Listing... Done
astmbi/unknown 1.0 arm64
```

```
root@debian:/home/biochemistry# apt show astmbi
N: Unable to locate package astmbi
N: Unable to locate package astmbi
E: No packages found
```

```
root@debian:/home/biochemistry# apt install astmbi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package astmbi
root@debian:/home/biochemistry#
```

Comment: I was making a mistake. In control file of the package it was arm64 (actually it should be amd64). But can somebody explain why list is successful and  show  is unsuccessful